# Define FK where target table does not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, batch-processing, suspend

When I create table that has definition of FK's directly in CREATE command and target table does not exists yet, results in error.

Can checking, if target table exists, be somehow suspended?

my DBMS is Postgres.

Example (pseudocode):

```
create table "Bar"
    foo_id integer FK of "Foo"."id",
    someattr text;

create table "Foo"
    id integer;
```

Example is in wrong order, thats why it wont run.

I'm trying to recreate databse in batch, based on definitions in many sql files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create table that has definition of FK's directly in CREATE command and target table does not exists yet, results in error.
>
> Can checking, if target table exists, be somehow suspended?

The best ways to deal with this are likely:

1. Create your tables in the correct order, or
2. Create the constraints
   outside the table creation, after all tables are created.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force is always an option.

Keep on running your DDL scripts in until you get a run with no errors.

More elegance requires a sequential structuring of your scripts.

Adding existence checks is possible, but I am not too familiar with the postgres metadata.

Comment: I think that correct structure of ddl commands is only way here. First create base tables and then add FK using alter command.